# Paste values & Name of file being within a cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Trying to use the below code to paste the data as values onto a separate sheet. Also I want the new sheet name to be from a cell reference from the original sheet

```
Private Sub cmdSave()
Dim sFileName As String
Dim WB As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

sFileName = "MyFileName.csv"
'Copy the contents of required sheet ready to paste into the new CSV
Sheets(1).Range("A1:T85").Copy 'Define your own range

'Open a new XLS workbook, save it as the file name
Set WB = Workbooks.Add
With WB
    .Title = "MyTitle"
    .Subject = "MySubject"
    .Sheets(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    .SaveAs "MyDirectory\" & sFileName, xlCSV
    .Close
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you hard coded the value of your file name to be "MyFileName.csv" in the line: `sFileName = "MyFileName.csv"`

To use the value of a cell you can use a reference to the cell of your preference. To use Cell B1 on the first worksheet of the workbook you are running your code from you can use: `sFileName = Thisworkbook.worksheets(1).Cells(1,2).value`

To paste data as values only you can use paste special, just as you normally would.  Replace the `.Paste` in `ActiveSheet.Paste` by `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. By default `.PasteSpecial` can't work on `Activesheet`alone, so replace `Activesheet` with `Activesheet.Range("A1")`

Comment: If my answer was helpfull to you please consider to accept (green check) and/or upvote it.